# Displaying big data set on Google Maps?

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, tiles, big-data

I have a pretty large polygon shapefile (almost 1.5 million buildings) that I want to display in Google Maps. As the KML would be far too big, I have to create tiles, right?

I don't want to host my own server, but just upload the tiles on my site. But how do I create the tiles for such a shapefile?

TileMill seems not working with such a large shapefile. It has to be Google Maps as I want to use the geolocation service that works best for the country the data is from.

Any hints?

Comment: can you just display small amounts of data for the area of interest? Do you have a database?

Comment: Should work as well in full zoom out. I could host a PostGIS database, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at gogeo Platform (www.gogeo.io) or CartoDb (http://cartodb.com)? I guess that Google Maps can't handle with millions of polygons. goGeo was made to work with Geospatial Big Data and CartoDb was built upon Postgis.

Answer (score 0):

Google's table fusion might be a good place to start. 
https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232?hl=en

Comment: It's too big: More than 100k lins and 100MB